# How to convert a Microsoft Word document to Google Docs format without having to download and re-upload again?

Tags: google-drive, file-conversion, google-docs

I currently have several Microsoft Word documents that are sitting on my Google Drive and were uploaded over the past few months. I understand that it is possible to **convert Microsoft Word documents to Google Docs format** during file upload time, but is it possible to convert documents *after* uploading them to Google Drive without having to download and re-upload the same document again?

Comment: Unfortunately, the conversion is not perfect. If you use special software like Mathtype which makes special characters like radical signs and such. The conversion process does not work. Plan text works OK. So technical papers with special characters used in Word Documents does convert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To convert a document, right click on it inside Google Drive. Choose *Open with* → *Google Docs*. A new window will be opened with the document in Google Docs format and it is saved inside the same folder in your Google Drive.

Comment: Wow, not intuitive.

Comment: In addition to not intuitive, it does not always keep the formatting you would expect. But can be a time saver!. This also works with other Google file formats such as Excel to Sheets.

Comment: When you open a doc this way, the fonts menu is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Drive add-ons such as:

- [DriveConverter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/driveconverter/pnijkabgdodbjffhlmbnhlccpkfappil) ([Website](https://www.driveconverter.com/))

  > Convert Word and Excel files to PDF and more.
  >
  > Convert files from your browser without downloading any conversion software.
- [Save Cloud files to Google Drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-cloud-files-to-googl/mjkbgfpkicedehbkjpadejnkdfdocegk)

  > This app allows you to save Dropbox, OneDrive, Box, Flickr files to Google Drive directly.
  >
  > Supports convert docx, pptx, xlsx, pdf, odt, jpg... formats to Google Document Formats.
- and [other](https://chrome.google.com/webstore).

For Google format to PDF, check: [How do I convert a Google doc to PDF without downloading it?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/90158/22759)