# How do I convert from a Google document to PDF without downloading it?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, pdf, file-conversion

I'd like to convert **from a Google document to PDF** and have it just appear in Google Drive, without having to choose "download as" and then re-upload. There's an "email as attachment" option where you can select PDF, but I'd like to be able to share a link to the converted PDF instead of email it.

Related [How to convert a Microsoft Word document to Google Docs format without having to download and re-upload again?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39329/how-do-i-convert-a-microsoft-word-document-to-google-docs-format-without-having), which is the reverse of what I want.

Comment: Hook https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/8106/10579

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate.

Comment: Simply pressing Ctrl. P works for me; opens a PDF in a new tab

Answer (score 8):

1. Click 'Print' or the icon for the printer in the Google Drive.
2. At the 'Destination' field, click the 'Change' button and choose "Save to Google Drive" as your destination. If "Save to Google Drive" does not display as an option among your printers, select 'Show All' at the bottom of your list and it should display. Or, type 'google drive' in the 'Search Destinations' field.
3. Click 'Save'
4. Go to your Google Drive homepage and select 'Recent' to display your new .pdf file
5. Rename or organize at will.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer; it does exactly what you want and doesn't require add-ons. Although it is a bit sad that you can't achieve this through the File menu options (-1 for Google). Thanks.

Comment: You now need the "Save to Google Drive" chrome extension to do this. Otherwise works exactly as you stated.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [Driveconverter](https://www.driveconverter.com) which converts various types of existing files in your Google Drive to PDF on the fly, giving you choice to select file(s) and proceed with the conversion inside your Drive folder.

It also works through the Google Drive's right-click menu > Open file with.

At first, allowing permissions is needed in order to integrate it with your Google Drive account before start using it.

Though it is a unstable in case your document filename uses letters other than english.

Answer (score 1):

https://convertio.co/ allows to convert files **without downloading** and has much more supported formats than driveconverter

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Drive add-ons](https://chrome.google.com/webstore) such as:

- [DriveConverter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/driveconverter/pnijkabgdodbjffhlmbnhlccpkfappil)

  > A file converter for the web. Convert Word and Excel files to PDF and more. Convert files from your browser without downloading any conversion software.
- [PDF Converter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-converter/dmgnkfgleaamgbhhojkfijjmjmngokkb),
- [DOC to PDF](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/doc-to-pdf-convert-word-t/edicbnelggokkleolmdenmjimmhhjece) ([Homepage](https://smartsfile.com/doc-to-pdf/)),
- and [other](https://chrome.google.com/webstore).

Answer (score 0):

I used my IPad

1. Select “Send a copy” while google doc is open
2. Select PDF
3. Select “Copy to drive” as destination