# Is there a way to convert gmail attachments to gmail docs, and replace them in the message with links to the drive file?

Tags: gmail, gmail-attachments

My Google drive folder is at 12.8 GB.  11 of that is gmail, with a ton of photos sent back and forth between me and my customers.

Gmail doesn't include mid resolution photos (which most are, and I don't mind the rest being converted)  Gmail also doesn't include converted files -- pdf's, word docs converted to google docs, excel sheets converted to google docs.

Is there a way to replace attachments with links to the corresponding google file?

Answer (score 1):

The Gmail web UI doesn't include a built-in way to do that. It could be possible by using an IMAP email client like Outlook (for Desktop) that supports the edit of received emails. In the case of Outlook this could be automated by using VBA and some Google APIs to upload the attachments to Google Drive.

I don't think that this could be possible by using the Gmail Service from Google Apps Script, but perhaps this could be possible by using the advanced Gmail service / GMail API.

To ask for a third party app, I suggest you to look into the G Suite Marketplace and to post a question in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Related

- [How to convert a Microsoft Word document to Google Docs format without having to download and re-upload again?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/39329/88163)
- [Replace Gmail attachments with Dropbox/Google Drive download link](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/49823/88163)
- [Can I convert a MS Word document to a Google Document format using GAS?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/56937/88163)